# If $\mathcal{D}$ is disjoint family and $E$ is $\sigma$-finite, then $\{D\in \mathcal{D}: \mu(D\cap E)>0\}$ is countable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

**Problem**

Let $\mu$ be a measure over $S$, $\sigma$-ring of $X$ . Let $E$ be a $\sigma$-finite set of $S$, and $\mathcal{D}\subset S$ such that $D_1,D_2\in\mathcal{D}$ with $D_1\neq D_2$ implies $D_1\cap D_2=\emptyset$.

Show that $\{D\in\mathcal{D} : \mu(D\cap E)>0\}$ is countable.

**Attempt**

Following the idea in [Is a family of disjoints atoms in $\sigma$-finite neasurable space at most countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073526/is-a-family-of-disjoints-atoms-in-sigma-finite-neasurable-space-at-most-count)
Calling $\mathcal{F}_c=\{D\cap E : D\in\mathcal{D}, \mu(D\cap E)>c\}$, we just need to show that $$ \mathcal{F}_0 =\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\mathcal{F}_{1/n}\quad \text{is countable}$$
How can I prove $\mathcal{F}_c$ is countable?

**Note**
$\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite, just $E$.

$E$ is $\sigma$-finite if there exists $\{E_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset S$ such that $E\subset \cup_n E_n$ and $\mu(E_n)<+\infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

P.D. Would you suggest me an appropriate title for this question?

Comment: Couldn't we directly prove that $\mathcal{F}_0$ is countable? Skipping the step where we prove $\mathcal{F}_c$ is countable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_n$ be as in the definition of $\sigma$-finite. Note that any $D$ with $\mu(D\cap E)>0$ must have $\mu(D\cap E_n)>\frac1k$ for some $n$ and $k$. For any $n$ and $k$, the inequality $\mu(D\cap E_n)>\frac1k$ can hold for at most $k\mu(E_n)$ disjoint sets $D$. So
$$
\{D\in\mathcal D:\mu(D\cap E)>0\}\subseteq
\bigcup_n\bigcup_k
\{D\in\mathcal D:\mu(D\cap E_n)>\frac1k\}
$$
is a countable union of finite sets, hence countable.